# Is acceptable to say a year or a dates with each the numbers?

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

Shortly, is accepted if I say

> 1997 => one nine nine seven
>
> 02/10/1997 => zero two, ten, one nine nine seven
>
> 02/10/1997 => two, ten, one nine nine seven

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean here when you write "Shortly?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple conversation this would not be usual, and in some cases there is some possibility for confusion. When dictating information, perhaps over the phone, then we might spell things out that way.

Years: we normally split the year, separate its century component. So

> Nineteen Ninety-Seven
>
> Twenty Sixteen

And often omit the century if it is obvious from context.

> Back in ninety-five I was working in ...

Days and Months: It is common to use the numbers rather than your example of the digits of the numbers. So

> Two, Ten
>
> Nine, Eleven

However there are different conventions around the world for expressing months and days, some places put the month first, others the day first. So in fact looking at your date I don't know if you mean February 10th or October 2nd. Hence I would recommend using the name of the month

> 2nd October
>
> September 11th

Comment: Awesome explanation and I understand now :) thanks ;)